# Xamarin Device Manager only shows Google play images in device manager screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have observed the following in the new Xamarin Device Manager for VS 2017 (15.6.4). 
If i try to create a new device i can only choose between system images for sdk versions where the Google Play image has been installed. 
But if i edit the device profile that was the default and created with the google api's not the play ones, i can without any issue choose all the system images installed. So it seems the Xamarin Device manager only looks for Google play system images and not for the google apis ones.

So a workaorund for now would be to copy the "existing" 7.1 device profile and edit that.

Can someone confirm this issue ?

[Image shows that only Android 7.0 and 8.0 can be selected and are installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCdmX.png)

[SDk Manager shows that several system images are installed not just the ones we are able to choose in the create new dialog.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtBAg.png)

[If editing device profile that was based on Google APIs not Play all images can be used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds4Rj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch Google Play/Google APIs/Default images via `tag.id` property in the editor.

Comment: Thanks this did solve the issue. Was not aware of that feature.

Comment: This will be much easier to find in the next version of the device manager tool!